# Firebase Database Query Rating for multiple users and Foods

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with write a correct Rating Query for multiple users and multiple for Foods order android app.

This is a Firebase data as a json form:

```
"Rating" : {
  "1234555" : {
    "14" : {
      "comment" : "KKK",
      "foodId" : "14",
      "rateValue" : "4",
      "userPhone" : "1234555"
    }
  }
}
```

"1234555" is UserID   and "14" is the FoodId

```
private void getRatingFood(String foodId) {
   Query foodRating=Ratings.child(foodId).orderByChild("foodId").equalTo(foodId);

    foodRating.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        int count=0,sum=0;
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Rating item=postSnapShot.getValue(Rating.class);
              sum+=Integer.parseInt(item.getRateValue());
              count++;

            }

            if(count!=0){
                float avg=sum/count;
                ratingBar.setRating(avg);
            }
    }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I think my Query statement is wrong because it can't access to inside attributes.

Comment: Can you try with this: `Query foodRating=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Rating").child("1234555").orderByChild("foodId").equalTo("14");`?

Comment: I think you should add index for the same key in firebase rules.